$I = \displaystyle\int \dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2 -1}}$. Two different answers using different assumptions. Which is correct?
Consider this integral $I = \displaystyle\int \dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2 -1}}$.
The integrand is defined for $x > 1$ or $x < -1$, so it makes sense to consider two cases.
Assume $x < -1$. Then let $t = \dfrac1x < 0 \implies dx = -\dfrac{1}{t^2}\,dt$ and $\sqrt{x^2 - 1} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{-t}$.
Thus, $$I = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\dfrac{1}{t^2}\,dt = \displaystyle\int\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\arcsin{(t)} + C = \arcsin{\left(\dfrac1x\right)}+C.$$
It's clear that if we assume $x > 1$, then by the same substitution, we have $t > 0$ and $\sqrt{x^2 -1 } = \dfrac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t}.$ Thus, $I = -\arcsin{\left(\dfrac1x\right)} + C$ for $x > 1$.
Combining two cases, we have $$I = -\arcsin{\left(\dfrac{1}{|x|}\right)} +C,\quad\forall x>1 \,\text{or}\,x<-1.$$
Now, consider this an integral of a differential binomial $$I = x^{-1}(x^2-1)^{-\frac12}\,dx$$where $m = -1, n = 2, p = -\frac12,$ and $\dfrac{m+1}{n} = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Assume $x < -1$.  By my textbook, I'm supposed to make the substitution $x^2 - 1 = t^2$.
Thus, $x = -\sqrt{t^2 +1}$ and $dx = \dfrac{-t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\,dt$.
To transform the other terms into expressions per $t$, I'm forced to assume either $t >0$ or $t <0$.
Assume $t > 0$, then $x^{-1} = \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{t^2 +1}}$ and $(x^2-1)^{-\frac12} = \dfrac1t$. Hence, $$I = \int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\cdot\dfrac1t\cdot\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\,dt=\int\dfrac{dt}{t^2+1}=\arctan{t}+C.$$It's clear that for $t< 0$, we have $I = -\arctan{t} + C$. Checking the answer using my calculator (by plugging in specific limits for definite integral), it looks like $I = \arctan{t} + C$ is the correct answer, but the substitution doesn't appear to require $t > 0$. Please advise.
Thank you!

$\arccos{\frac{1}{x}}$ and $\arctan{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ are identical. Also $\arccos{\frac{1}{x}}$ and $-\arcsin{\frac{1}{x}}$ differ by a constant.

Alternatively, you can transform it into a standard integral by multiplying and dividing by $\text{sgn}x$ since $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sec^{-1}x=\frac1{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

On substituting $x^2-1=t^2$, the domain of $t$ is immaterial since for each domain of $t$, the final anti-derivative obtained(in terms of $x$) would be the same. This is because the expression for $t$ in terms of $x$ in each domain would be different.
$\textbf{Case 1: } t>0$

If $x>1$,
$$x=\sqrt{t^2+1}, t=\sqrt{x^2-1}, \mathrm dx=\frac{t\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
$$\implies \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\int\frac1{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\cdot\frac1{\not{t}}\cdot\frac{\not{t}\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
$$\implies \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\tan^{-1}t+C=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}+C$$
If $x<-1$,
$$x=-\sqrt{t^2+1}, t=\sqrt{x^2-1}, \mathrm dx=\frac{-t\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
$$\implies \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\int\frac{-1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\cdot\frac1{\not{t}}\cdot\frac{-\not{t}\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
$$\implies \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\tan^{-1}t+C=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}+C$$

$\textbf{Case 2: } t<0$

If $x>1$,
$$x=\sqrt{t^2+1}, t=-\sqrt{x^2-1}, \mathrm dx=\frac{t\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
$$\implies \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\int\frac1{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\cdot\frac{-1}{\not{t}}\cdot\frac{\not{t}\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
$$\implies \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=-\tan^{-1}t+C=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}+C$$
If $x<-1$,
$$x=-\sqrt{t^2+1}, t=-\sqrt{x^2-1}, \mathrm dx=\frac{-t\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
$$\implies \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\int\frac{-1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\cdot\frac{-1}{\not{t}}\cdot\frac{-\not{t}\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$
$$\implies \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=-\tan^{-1}t+C=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}+C$$

It can be seen that in each case,
$$\boxed{\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}+C}$$
This is equivalent to your first answer, since:

$x>0$
$$\implies -\sin^{-1}\frac1{x}=-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=-\frac{\pi}2+\cot^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=-\frac{\pi}2+\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

$x<0$
$$\implies -\sin^{-1}\frac1{-x}=-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=-\frac{\pi}2+\cot^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=-\frac{\pi}2+\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}$$



Thank you very much! I was stopping short at the expression per $t$. It's true that when transformed to $x$, both cases ($t>0$ and $t<0$) lead to the same answer.

@ten_to_tenth happy to assist, mate :D!

I have one more question and would greatly appreciate your help. Is it necessary to consider both cases, ($x > 1$ and $x < -1$)? Is there any way where we can integrate this function without considering different intervals of $x$? Thanks!

@ten_to_tenth yes, you definitely can, by using $x=|x|\text{sgn}x$ and $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. For example, while substituting $x^2-1=t^2$, $x=\text{sgn}x\sqrt{t^2+1}$.

Thank you very much!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For the integral $$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}dx$$ multiply the numerator and denominator by $x$.
Let $$I=\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}dx$$
$$\implies I=\int \frac{x}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}dx$$
Now substitute $x^{2}=u$ which will fetch you $xdx=\frac{1}{2}du$
$$\implies I=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u(\sqrt{u-1})}du$$
Now for simpler substitute $u=\sec^{2}(t)$ which will fetch $du=2\sec^{2}(t)\tan(t)dt$
Therefore
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2\sec^{2}(t)\tan(t)}{\sec^{2}(t)\tan(t)}dt$$
$$I=\sec^{-1}(\sqrt{u})+C$$
$$I=\sec^{-1}(x)+C$$

Using trigonometric substitution to evaluate integrals with radicals needs to split cases according to the domain of the substitution. On the other hand, the substitution $y=\sqrt {x^2-1}$ may be helpful.
$$d y  =\frac{2 x}{2 \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x =\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{x}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x \\
& =\int \frac{d y}{y^2+1} \\ &=\tan^{-1} y+C\\
& =\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$
